# awk + how to get latest numbers in file but exclude number until 4 digit

Tags: awk, sed

we have file like the following

`more file`

```
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hdfs hdfs         30 2021-06-09 07:10 /noij/gtdf/license_alerts/alert_1_1623222654527
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hdfs hdfs         30 2021-06-09 07:10 /noij/gtdf/license_alerts/alert_1_1623222654679
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hdfs hdfs         30 2021-06-09 07:10 /noij/gtdf/license_alerts/alert_1_1623222654744
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hdfs hdfs         30 2021-06-09 08:02 /noij/gtdf/license_alerts/alert_1_1623225746040_69
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hdfs hdfs         30 2021-06-09 08:02 /noij/gtdf/license_alerts/alert_1_1623225746059_66
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hdfs hdfs         30 2021-06-09 08:02 /noij/gtdf/license_alerts/alert_1_1623225746061_65
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hdfs hdfs         30 2021-06-09 08:02 /noij/gtdf/license_alerts/alert_1_1623225746162_65
```

while I need to take the last numbers but exclude if the number contain 1-3 digit

expected results should be

```
1623222654527
1623222654679
1623222654744
```

so my approach until now is

```
sed s'/_/ /g' file | awk '{print $NF}'
```

but its print

```
1623222654527
1623222654679
1623222654744
69
66
65
65
```

how to improve my syntax i n order to exclude the latest number that have 1 or 2 or 3 digit?

so we get the output like this

```
1623222654527
1623222654679
1623222654744
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?:

```
$ awk -F_ 'length($NF)>3{print $NF}' file
```

Output:

```
1623222654527
1623222654679
1623222654744
```

With `_` as field separator, if the length of the last field `$NF` is greater than 3, output the last field.

Answer (score 4):

With `grep`:

```sh
$ grep -oE '[0-9]{4,}$' ip.txt
1623222654527
1623222654679
1623222654744
```

Answer (score 1):

If there should be an underscore present, using `gnu grep` with `-P` for  Perl-compatible regular expressions:

```
grep -oP ".*_\K\d{4,}$" file
```

The pattern matches:

- `.*_` Match until the last underscore
- `\K` Clear the match buffer
- `\d{4,}$` Match 4 or more digits until the end of the string

Output

```
1623222654527
1623222654679
1623222654744
```

---

Or using `sed`

```
sed -nE 's/.*_([0-9]{4,})$/\1/p' file
```

- `-E` extended regex
- `-n` suppress automatic printing
- `/p` print the line

Output

```
1623222654527
1623222654679
1623222654744
```